# Inserted SUMIF function into cell VBA. Expected end of statement

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

```
Dim ACHRowCount As Integer
ACHRowCount = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'ACH CREDIT TOTALSCells
 Cells(ACHRowCount, 18).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUMIF(S3:S" & ACHRowCount & ", "<0")"
```

Basically, I have a macro that needs to insert a formula into a cell that sums only the negative values in a column. ACHRowCount is the number of rows in the column. When I try to run this code it says

> Error: Expected End Of Statement.

Comment: Double check your double quotes.

Comment: Thank you this worked. If possible could you explain to me the purpose of including double quotes ""<0""?

Comment: I doubt it worked properly as is missing an argument

Comment: The double quotes escapes the inner so they are recognised as needing to be retained in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

1. Name the sheet being worked with
2. Use `Option Explicit` at top of code
3. Use `Long` not `Integer`
4. Add sum range argument to `SUMIF` e.g. `T1:T3`. This is missing in your code.
5. Double up on `""` inside string

**Code:**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ACHRowCount As Long

    With ActiveSheet '<= change to actual sheet name
        ACHRowCount = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(ACHRowCount, 18).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUMIF(S3:S" & ACHRowCount & ", ""<0"",T1:T3)"
    End With

End Sub
```